# When I get the row index from numpy array: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I trying to implement "Brute Force" for Knapsack problem, I randomly generating table of values and costs. My BruteForce returns corrects answers but sometimes it returns TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars. The problem is in that line "bestItems.append(int(np.where(np.all(table==element, axis=1))[0]))"

```
def BruteForce(table):
    wholeWeight = table[:,0].sum()
    bagWeight = 0.5 * wholeWeight
    bestScore = 0
    bestItems = []
    for num in range(len(table)):
        for com in combinations(table,num+1):
            WEIGHT = sum([elem[0] for elem in com])
            COST = sum([elem[1] for elem in com])
            if WEIGHT <= bagWeight and bestScore < COST:
                bestScore = COST
                bestItems = []
                for element in com:
                    bestItems.append(int(np.where(np.all(table==element, axis=1))[0]))
    return bestScore, bestItems
```

For example:

```
np.array([[2, 8],
 [2, 8],
 [6 ,7],
 [6, 5],
 [6, 1]])
```

Returns:
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

But if table =:

```
np.array([[9, 6],
 [4, 7],
 [8 ,9],
 [9, 7],
 [3, 4]])
```

Returns: (20, [1, 2, 4])

Comment: Why the `int()` call?  `int(np.array([1,2]))` can produce this error.

Comment: I call ```int()``` because "np.where(np.all(table==element, axis=1))[0]" return list with index.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output. As an aside, you seem to be mixing/combining multiple naming conventions, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style, unless there is a good reason not to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [45]: table = np.array([[2, 8], 
    ...:  [2, 8], 
    ...:  [6 ,7], 
    ...:  [6, 5], 
    ...:  [6, 1]])                                                              

In [47]: np.all(table==[2,8], axis=1)                                           
Out[47]: array([ True,  True, False, False, False])
In [48]: np.where(np.all(table==[2,8], axis=1))                                 
Out[48]: (array([0, 1]),)
In [49]: np.where(np.all(table==[2,8], axis=1))[0]                              
Out[49]: array([0, 1])
In [50]: int(np.where(np.all(table==[2,8], axis=1))[0])                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-cb698d9f7e05> in <module>
----> 1 int(np.where(np.all(table==[2,8], axis=1))[0])

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

The `where` produces a tuple of integer arrays.  The `int()` wrapper only works when there is exactly one match.

```
In [51]: int(np.where(np.all(table==[2,7], axis=1))[0])                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-294e3139501e> in <module>
----> 1 int(np.where(np.all(table==[2,7], axis=1))[0])

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
In [52]: int(np.where(np.all(table==[6,7], axis=1))[0])                         
Out[52]: 2
```

You need to handle the matches more robustly.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand now :D